# Circular imports on python app

Tags: python, flask

I'm beginning to learn python and [I'm following this tutorial on setting up Flask](http://maximebf.com/blog/2012/10/building-websites-in-python-with-flask/#.U7BP7ahjAsl), but I'm having some trouble understanding the author in how he lays out his files. From what I can gather, it seems like I'm running into a circular import problem and I can't trouble shoot it.

The files are set up as follows:

**`__init__.py`**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "something here";
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite://app.db"
```

**`app.py`**

```
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort, session
from app import app

@app.route('/')
.... some stuff here
```

**`models.py`**

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import app

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
.... some stuff here
```

**`manage.py`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask.ext.script import Manage, Shell, Server 
from app import app

manage = Manager(app)
manager.add_command("runserver", Server())
manager.add_command("shell", Shell())

@manager.command
def createdb():
   from app.models import db
   db.create_all()

manager.run()
```

The first error is being unable to start the server through running manage.py runserver. I was able to do it initially until I switched the files around initialized the app within init.py (originally I had everything located in app.py). I receive an error saying -

`ImportError: cannot import name app`

That aside, if I eliminate init.py and get the server up and running, I can't create a database because I receive an error stating -

`Import Error: no module named models` when running manage.py createdb

Comment: You're trying to import app, from app, within app?...

Comment: Does this relate to how the directories are named? I have my parent folder named "app", while in the tutorial the parent folder is named "example" and uses "from example import app", which is why I have it written out as "from app import app"

Comment: `from x import y` means ["from *module* x import the *names* y"](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules). Is your init file actually called *exactly* `init.py`? It should be `__init__.py`. It's purpose is to convert a directory into a *package*. You generally don't put much/any code in it.

Comment: Yes its named __init__. So from app import app is implying import app (the flask object) from the app.py file?

Comment: Well, yes - but within itself it doesn't mean anything. Rename your `init.py` file to `__init__.py` and have another read through the tutorial and have a read through of https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @IanClark: __init__ is what shows up when you type `__init__` without code-formatting it. @OP: Type backticks around stuff like that for inline code formatting.

Comment: @user2357112 hah, yeh I realised after posting, used to conventional MD of \*